# if statement not seem not be correct javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, if-statement

I am having problem with my `if` statements, `else` and `else if`.

This is my code:

```
function draw(d) {
    var testarray = JSON.parse(a);
    var testarray1 = JSON.parse(a1);
    var testarray2 = JSON.parse(a2);

    var Yaxis = $("#<%=hidden10.ClientID%>").val();

    if (d == 1)
    {
        var c = testarray
        Yaxis = 'data';   
    }
    else if (d == 1)
    {
        var e = testarray1
        Yaxis = 'data1';
    }
    else if (d == 2)
    {
        var c = testarray
        Yaxis = 'data2';
    }
    else if (d == 2)
    {
        var e = testarray1
        Yaxis = 'data3';
    }
    else(d == 3)
    {
        var e = testarray1
        Yaxis = 'data4';
    }
```

When I debug the code, it only hits `d==1` and then goes to `d==3` and skips out `1` and `2`. For the `yaxis` it only shows `data4`, and doesn't show `data`, `data1` and `data2` on my graph.

Apparently my `else` statement is not correct, but I have [googled the `if` statement](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptelseif.php) and it seems that I have done it correctly, but it's not working.

`d` is a radio button calling from code behind in vb:

```
Select Case RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value
    Case 1


        Dim Yaxis As String
        If RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value = 1 Then
            Yaxis = "data"
        End If


        hidden10.Value = Yaxis


        For Each row In Year1
            testarray.Add(row("kWh"))
        Next row


        Dim arrayJsonTest1 As String = serializer1.Serialize(testarray)
        Dim arrayJson11 As String = serializer1.Serialize(testarray1)


        hidden.Value = arrayJsonTest1
        hidden1.Value = arrayJson11
        hidden2.Value = arrayJson12


        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "draw", "javascript:draw(1);", True)
```

Comment: what is d in your code??

Comment: d is radio button calling from code behind in vb.

Comment: check the answer..you gave the wrong condition!!!

Comment: The first two `if` has the same condition, so the second one will never happen. The last `else(d == 3)`, did you forget *else if*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            if (d == 1)
                           {
               var c = testarray
               Yaxis = 'data';

          }

          else if (d == 1)//why is this same?
          {
              var e = testarray1
              Yaxis = 'data1';
              }
```

**if** and **else if** have the same condition.Correct it.

```
               if (d == 1)
               {
               var c = testarray
               Yaxis = 'data';
              var e = testarray1
              Yaxis = 'data1';
              }
              else if(d == 3)
              {
              var e = testarray1
              Yaxis = 'data4';
              }
```

Comment: the data is diffrent, am trying to call d==1 for the first radio button. so when it hits that it shows diffrent data

Comment: for d==1 i want var c = testarray to show data, and var e = testarray1 to show data1..

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue (ignoring the duplicates that another answer already highlighted) is towards the end of your code:

```
       else (d == 3) 
       {
           var e = testarray1
           Yaxis = 'data4';
       }
```

In this section, you're not actually doing an `if`; as a result, the JavaScript parser is treating this as:

```
       else true;

       {
           var e = testarray1
           Yaxis = 'data4';
       }
```

where `(d == 3)` evaluates to `true`, and is then followed by a separate code block that updates the value of `Yaxis` independently of the `if ... else` block it followed.

A much neater way would be to use the `switch` statement instead:

```
switch (d) {
    case 1:
        Yaxis = 'data';
        break;
    case 2:
        Yaxis = 'data1';
        break;
    ... etc .. 
 }
```

<del>Note that your values for 'c', 'e' etc are defined as `var` inside the `{` and `}` brackets, and thus their values will be unavailable outside those.</del>

Comment: Well spotted! Had missed that one

Comment: so will the last one be else if

Comment: when i change the last one to else if, then all the data is the same

Comment: @mali Take a look at the update; for something like this, `switch` is more appropriate anyway, it's significantly more readable. Written from memory so may not be 100% correct.

Comment: In javascript the `{}` do *not* define a new scope. Variables declared inside *are* visible outside. OK, it's better form to then declare them outside, so you "see" the correct scope.

Comment: @HansKesting I'll amend my answer, thanks. For some reason I've always assumed that was the case (and thus avoided doing it myself).